# Can no longer deploy a web project to Google App Engine due to new organization assignment

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, deployment, project, organization

I'm trying to deploy a new web project to Google app engine, but google now requires new projects to be created under specific organizations. All of my older projects have no organization assigned, and deploy as they should. Is there a way to direct the project to deploy to a specific organization in the App Engine Project settings? I believe this requirement is fairly recent on Googles part. Im using Eclipse Neon V4.6.2 with the most recent google app engine plugin.

Thanks!

Comment: Confusingly there are two "most recent Google App Engine plugins," Google Plugin for Eclipse and Cloud Tools for Eclipse. Which one are you using? Have you tried deploying from the command line, and if so what command did you use?

Comment: Got it to work. There's a  Java plug in on the google side that needs to be added.